# Mocha/Chai testing an office add-in, but Mocha keeps claiming 'Office' is undefined?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, office-js, chai

I'm new to mocha/chai/testing in general, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

My code (a Word add-in) works perfectly fine by itself, but when I try to run mocha tests on it, it reaches this initilize function a few lines in:

```
Office.initialize = (reason) => {
    $('#sideload-msg').hide();
    $('#app-body').show();
};
```

and just stops running, spitting out this error:

```
ReferenceError: Office is not defined
```

Earlier it was spitting out the same thing but for XMLHttpRequest (`ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`) but I managed to get around it by adding this to the top of the page:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

I *would* try to do the same thing for Office, but I'm not even sure what I'd have to `require`, and I can't find any information online.

This is the entirety of my test.js page if it helps:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../src/index.js');
const should = chai.should();

const APIURL = "https://example.com";

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('API Calls', function() {
    it('should return 200 status code on /api/context-key GET', function (done) {
        chai.request(server)
            .get(APIURL + '/api/context-key')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            })
    });
});
```

I'm not even sure I'm structuring it correctly? It's using the index.js page of my add-in as `server` but what I'm trying to do is test that an API with the URL `https://example.com/api/context-key` returns a 200 status code when sent a GET request. Am I way off? Like I said, I'm completely new to testing :/

EDIT: Actually that XMLHttpRequest fix made the tests run, but broke the app.

Comment: I don't know much about testing, but Office.js cannot initialize when it is not running in an add-in in an Office application. I presume that the tests run outside of an Office application. So even if you found a way to reference and define `Office`, it would not initialize. You'd get an error in the console saying that Office is not running in an Office host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you've found an answer to this by now, but I'll try to explain as best as I can.

What you're trying to do with your Mocha tests looks like to be *e2e testing*.

But you haven't set-it up in a way to do the e2e testing. Judging by the code I'm seeing, you're unit-testing the server calls - that's ok. But `Office.js` is on the client side, which means for properly testing its functionality, you'd have to load the page (in a headless browser probably) - and then do whatever you want to do.

There are tools for this, see some interesting reads below:

- [Testing Front-End Code](https://hackernoon.com/testing-your-frontend-code-part-iii-e2e-testing-e9261b56475)
- [E2E testing with Node and Selenium](https://marmelab.com/blog/2016/04/19/e2e-testing-with-node-and-es6.html)
- [E2E testing with Puppeteer and Jest](https://blog.logrocket.com/end-to-end-testing-react-apps-with-puppeteer-and-jest-ce2f414b4fd7)

Even then testing stuff related to `Office.js` is not going to be easy, because it requires the external context from the Office environment (like the Windows / Mac / Web clients). So as an example, something like `Office.context.document.settings` would not work by default and you would have to inject another mocking script to make sure the methods that you're looking to invoke are mocked.

Testing individual components of the front-end is actually fairly easy at this stage, what I can recommend is to **never** use `Office.js` methods in your front-end code directly, always use them through a wrapper and call that wrapper. That way you only need to mock the wrapper and the rest of your code becomes testable.

To give an example only a single file like `officewrappers.js` should contain references to your Office.js methods. In there you can have,

```
/*
 This file and its methods are the only reference that you have
 to Office.context... in no where else you should directly invoke
 these methods but use the OfficeService methods. That way 
 you can mock the OfficeService and you're good to go!
 */
OfficeService.GetDocumentBody = function() {
    // Some office method
    Office.context.document.getBody....
}
```

Comment: @Thorium I'd appreciate the green tick if it qualifies as the answer.